# Setting TempData in HttpApplication event handler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a module, and I'd like to set TempData dictionary value when specific conditions are met, and I'd like to do it on Application_EndRequest event.

How can I access TempData dictionary for current HttpContext within specific event handler?

Comment: Can't you implement that with an ActionFilter? http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Comment: No sorry, I specifically need to implement it within Application event handlers :(